# How to get data from Parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform

After pushing the data on parse.com's app.I want to retrieve that data.I am defining the api_key and client_key in the android code.Now the problem is that every application installed will be having the same keys.SO if any device trying to fetch the data using parse query will recieve that data.if all the (client-server) sets are having the same set of keys than it will be the possible that data will be delivered to wrong destination.Should I have to assign every(client-server) set a new set of keys? what is the solution.I am new to parse please help.

Comment: Is your question about getting data from parse, or about having different the keys and channel..

Comment: Suppose I have a X-Server Y-client.
Now X will recieve some data from Y every 10 minutes.
X-Y is having (A-B) Key set.
but Now if there is Another set (P-Q) of server and client they will also have the same set(A-B) of keys.
So (P-Q) will also recieve what (A-B) is recieving.But I want to sepate every set.

Answer (score 0):

Referring your comment, if you have different server then you can create different channel with using same keys for all clients.
What parse requires from you is , you should subscribe to a channel on which you will receive a push notification.
So keeping different channel you will achieve this. You just need to send channel to the client by some means.
e.g for client x channel will be `serverA_yourchannelCreationLogic`.. 
you can even use server **ipaddress** or **hostname** etc, to prefix the channel.

Comment: Oh I am sorry I was giving you an example.X-Y and P-Q are mobile devices.You can think it as on Y i have installed a malicious code giving some data to X.But if x-y and p-q are having the same set of keys it will create problems.

Comment: I think it will not create problem if you have different channels for x-y and p-q even having same keys for both

Comment: ok how to do this please provide some example.I dont know so much about parse.

Comment: check the parse demo app  and also the steps provided on website to work with the parse

Comment: I checked the parse demo.I got an idea that i can subscribe to the channel for each device.as we know that each row is identified uniquely by objectId.there was some examples showing how to get objectId in the same devices application.Like in my app the Y(Client) can get the object ID easliy but I want to retrieve that data in the device X(Server).How can I retrieve the same data pushed by Y in X.As the object id can be saved in the client but what about server.because I am able to get data back only if i am having the object ids.and every object id is generated automatically.